# IP forwarding not working on Vagrant + Ansible scenario

Tags: debian, ip, ansible, vagrant, forwarding

This is the scenario
[image]

It is created with Vagrant and configured with Ansible, but the specific problem I'm going to ask about here is why IP forwarding is not working when it should be working.

On the router VM, we can check IP forwarding is enabled because...

```
vagrant@router:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Here you have the info about the router interface connected with the client

```
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:aa:ef:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s7
    altname ens7
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feaa:efdb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In theory, forwarding *should* be working.

Now, let's go to the client and see its routes

```
vagrant@cliente:~$ ip r
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
192.168.121.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.121.233
```

The default route is modified by my playbook, so it points to the router interface as main gateway.

Here you have info about the interface on the client, the one which is connected to the router

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:89:9f:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s6
    altname ens6
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe89:9fbe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Ping to the router is working

```
vagrant@cliente:~$ ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.271 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.311 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1032ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.271/0.291/0.311/0.020 ms
```

If I try to ping to the Internet, it stops on the router

```
vagrant@cliente:~$ ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2038ms
```

You can check it better this way

```
vagrant@cliente:~$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  0.345 ms  0.268 ms  0.238 ms
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  0.207 ms  0.180 ms  0.156 ms
```

It clearly stops on the router, and forwarding is activated.

So at this point, I'm lost and I can't figure out what's happening. Everything should be working, should be.